# How to run multiple clients (my_account, my_bot) at the same time on pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I'm having trouble with running both 'my_account' and 'my_bot' at the same time. I need to do some tasks with Client('my_account') class and automatic reply to commands with Client('my_bot') class.

I've tried so many ways, but no results. Here is my code.

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram.handlers.message_handler import MessageHandler

from pyrogram import Client, compose

api_id = 12345678
api_hash = "1234567891a23456b7891234cde5f67f"
bot_token = "1234567891:ABCD1EFG234HI5jKL6MNopqRSt7UVwXyz8A"


async def dummy(client, message):
    await message.reply("heeloo")


async def main():
    apps = [
        Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash),
        Client("my_bot", api_id=api_id, bot_token=bot_token)
    ]
    await compose(apps)

    apps[0].add_handler(MessageHandler(dummy))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: For safety purposes, don't expose your private keys to the public. Use filler text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are adding the handler after calling `compose`, so it’ll never be added since `compose` blocks. Adding the handlers before the `compose` call should fix the problem:

```py
async def main():
    apps = [
        Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash),
        Client("my_bot", api_id=api_id, bot_token=bot_token)
    ]

    apps[0].add_handler(MessageHandler(dummy))

    await compose(apps)
```